# Jquery window resize with condition not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function in my jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 768)
  {
     $(".dummy").focus(function(){alert("Dummy");})
  }
}
```

And also:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 768)
        {
            $(".dummy").focus(function(){alert("Dummy");})
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `alert("Dummy");` is a representation of my function.

**Scenario 1:**
When I launch my webpage in a browser with a viewport width of more than 768 and focus on `.dummy`, the `alert("Dummy");` is not executed.

**Scenario 2:**
However, if I launch my webpage in a viewport width of less that 768, and then resize the width of the browser to more than 768. The `alert("Dummy");` is still executed when `.dummy` is focused.

Shouldn't it check for the condition  `if($(window).width() < 768)` and not allow 
`alert("Dummy");` to be executed when focused on `.dummy`?

What can I do ensure that `alert("Dummy");` is not executed when focused on `.dummy` in a situation such as **Scenario 2**? Taking into consideration that the user might go through **Scenario 1**.

Comment: Side note: You're attaching the `focus` event to `.dummy` every time the window changes sizes (and width is less than 768). That means if you keep resizing the window, and then focus on `.dummy`, your function will could fire way more than you're expecting.

Comment: As i said, the `alert()` is merely a representation of my functions. @Santi @blackandorangecat

Comment: @ErnestSoo Okay, so your function, regardless of what it does, could fire 100 times over.

Comment: Why would it? When the only time it will be fired is when focused upon. @Santi

Comment: @ErnestSoo: No. `focus()` binds an event handler. Every time you call `focus`, a *new* event handler is bound.

Comment: No, you're *adding an event listener* every time the `resize` event is fired, and `resize` is fired continuously as the window is resized, not just when the resize is completed.

Comment: @ErnestSoo Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1nm1zfzc/ - **WARNING:** This will popup hundreds, if not thousands, of alerts. If you don't believe me you can run this example, but be prepared to open your Task Manager ;)

Comment: @ErnestSoo Also, for future reference, you're missing a bunch of closing parentheses. Make sure that when you bind event handlers, you close them as such: `})`. In your example, you're only using a `}`, closing just the `function() { ...` portion.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Santi . I understand now after using your fiddle. However, I will apply the answer given below. But i will use your info for future use.

Comment: @ErnestSoo The answer below is the proper way to implement what you're going for, and removes the issue I've pointed out, so they go somewhat hand in hand! Glad I was able to demonstrate the issue for you, and good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to set the handler on `resize`. Just check for the window size at call time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dummy").focus(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 768)
        {
            alert('dummy');
        }
    });
});
```